# how can i send extra parameter to php selenium script

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver

i am using below php library to create selenium automatic website testing.
https://github.com/lmc-eu/steward

in this library script execute using below command. in script we can open browser and specific url in browser automatic. also we can set username and password in login form and we can trigger submit button. here url is static define in script but i want to pass dynamic url from command line when i execute command. but i can't find how to do that

below is a command to run selenium script

```
./vendor/bin/steward run tests chrome
```

i want to pass extra parameter to selenium script. how can i do that can any one help me to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can set an environment variable in your command line when executing the script. For instance, to pass a URL, you could modify your command like this:

```
URL="http://your.url" ./vendor/bin/steward run tests chrome
```

And simple pickup with:

```
$url = getenv('URL');
```

If you need to open browser and navigate to that URL, you can do it something like this:

```
$webDriver->get($url);
```

This line tells Selenium to navigate to the URL that was passed from the command line.